# onclick function is not working in php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to use some inline function for PHP on input tags..

So,this is is what I am doing.What is the proper way of doing this.

```
echo '<input type="button" value="+" class="addBtn" id="add'.$t->getAttribute('name').'" onclick="window.addField=function(){alert(\'hi\');}" />';
```

Comment: Hm, but what you are going to reach - in your code you create a link in window global varaible addField to function with alert

Comment: what is your exact requirement in that above code?

Comment: I just want to use jquery inline with on click,so for testing purpose I gave alert box,which is not working.This will make easy to understand may be
  echo '<input type="button" value="+"onclick="window.addField=function(){alert(\'hi\');}" />';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing currently is defining the function addField when the button is clicked.  To alert the text either change your code to the following:

```
echo '<input type="button" value="+" class="addBtn" id="add'.$t->getAttribute('name').'" onclick="alert(\'hi\');" />';
```

or add this script tag to your document's head section:

```
echo "<script>window.window.addField=function(){alert('hi');}</script>";
```

and then change the line to read:

```
echo '<input type="button" value="+" class="addBtn" id="add'.$t->getAttribute('name').'" onclick="window.addField" />';
```

Comment: Got it,your first line did the job for me,the thing is that I have to generate a form from xsd,and use its maxOccur field to dynamic generation of textboxes on the click of the button,as many click that many text box,so had to to use this method,no choice for me